# Friendly way to parse XDocument

Tags: c#, .net, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I have a class that various different XML schemes are created from. I create the various dynamic XDocuments via one (Very long) statement using conditional operators for optional elements and attributes.

I now need to convert the XDocuments back to the class but as they are coming from different schemes many elements and sub elements may be optional.  The only way I know of doing this is to use a lot of if statements.

This approach doesn't seem very LINQ and uses a great deal more code than when I create the XDocument so I wondered if there is a better way to do this?

An example would be to get

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root xmlns="somenamespace">
    <object attribute1="This is Optional" attribute2="This is required">
        <element1>Required</element1>
        <element1>Optional</element1>
        <List1>
            Optional List Of Elements
        </List1>
        <List2>
            Required List Of Elements
        </List2>
    </object>
</root>
```

Into

```
public class Object()
{
    public string Attribute1;
    public string Attribute2;
    public string Element1;
    public string Element2;
    public List<ListItem1> List1;
    public List<ListItem2> List2;
}
```

In a more LINQ friendly way than this:

```
public bool ParseXDocument(string xml)
{
    XNamespace xn = "somenamespace";            
    XDocument document = XDocument.Parse(xml);

    XElement elementRoot = description.Element(xn + "root");
    if (elementRoot != null)
    {
        //Get Object Element
        XElement elementObject = elementRoot.Element(xn + "object");
        if(elementObject != null)
        {
            if(elementObject.Attribute(xn + "attribute1") != null)
            {
                Attribute1 = elementObject.Attribute(xn + "attribute1");
            }
            if(elementObject.Attribute(xn + "attribute2") != null)
            {
                Attribute2 = elementObject.Attribute(xn + "attribute2");
            }
            else
            {
                //This is a required Attribute so return false
                return false;
            }
            //If, If/Elses get deeper and deeper for the next elements and lists etc.... 
        }
        else
        {
            //Object is a required element so return false
            return false;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //Root is a required element so return false
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Update: Just to clarify the ParseXDocument method is inside the "Object" class.  Every time an xml document is received the Object class instance has some or all of it's values updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Have a look at [XElement and](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff986933.aspx) [XAttribute Type Conversions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff986944.aspx).
- The [document root](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.root.aspx) is always non-null.
- Validate the object afterwards, so you don't have to implement validation twice (once when parsing and once before saving).

*Code:*

```
private static readonly XNamespace xn = "somenamespace";

public bool ParseXDocument(string xml)
{
    XDocument document = XDocument.Parse(xml);

    var obj = document.Root.Element(xn + "object");
    if (obj == null)
        return false;

    Attribute1 = (string)obj.Attribute("attribute1");
    Attribute2 = (string)obj.Attribute("attribute2");
    Element1 = (string)obj.Element(xn + "element1");
    Element2 = (string)obj.Elements(xn + "element1").ElementAtOrDefault(1);
    // ...

    return Validate();
}
```

Comment: Thanks DTB-Sorry should have made myself clearer.I'm not creating a new class, I'm updating values in an existing class. New values are sent through periodically and some to all values are updated per xml document received.  The ParseXDocument method would be inside the "Object" class.

Answer (score 0):

Below I have a couple of extension methods you can use that may help reach your desired readability. The code in it's current form does not support returning true/false depending on if all the required elements were found. I recommend adopting dtb's advice in that regard, and just parse out the details, and then perform validation on that.

There are downsides, such as repeated iteration over the XML sturcture, but with a bit of imagination I'm sure you could overcome that if it becomes an issue.

Here is what MyObject looks like:
    public class MyObject
    {
        public string Attribute1;
        public string Attribute2;
        public string Element1;
        public string Element2;
        public List List1;
        public List List2;

```
    public void ParseXDocument(string xml)
    {
        XNamespace xn = "somenamespace";            
        XDocument document = XDocument.Parse(xml);

        XElement elementRoot = document.Root;
        elementRoot.MatchElement(xn.GetName("object"), xObject => {
            xObject.MatchAttribute("attribute1", (x,a) => this.Attribute1 = (string)a);
            xObject.MatchAttribute("attribute2", (x,a) => this.Attribute2 = (string)a);
            xObject.MatchElement(xn.GetName("element1"), x => this.Element1 = (string)x);
            xObject.MatchElement(xn.GetName("element2"), x => this.Element2 = (string)x);
        });
    }
}
```

Here are the extension methods that support it:
    public static class XElementExtensions {

```
    public static XElement MatchAttribute(this XElement x, XName name, Action<XElement, XAttribute> action) {
        foreach (var a in x.Attributes(name)) {
            action(x, a);
        }

        return x;
    }

    public static XElement MatchElement(this XElement x, XName name, Action<XElement> action) {
        foreach (var child in x.Elements(name)) {
            action(child);
        }

        return x;
    }
}
```

And finally, here is some sample driver code I used in LinqPad to test it out:

```
void Main()
{
    var xml = @"<?xml version=""1.0""?>
<root xmlns=""somenamespace"">
    <object attribute1=""This is Optional"" attribute2=""This is required"">
        <element1>Required</element1>
        <element2>Optional</element2>
        <List1>
            Optional List Of Elements
        </List1>
        <List2>
            Required List Of Elements
        </List2>
    </object>
</root> 
    ";

    var o = new MyObject();

    o.ParseXDocument(xml);
    o.Dump();
}
```